# Under which conditions on $f$ do we've got $\sigma(X)=\sigma(f\circ X)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}')$ and $(\Omega'',\mathcal{A}'')$ be measurable spaces
- $X:\Omega\to\Omega'$ be $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{A}'$-measurable
- $f:\Omega'\to\Omega''$ be $\mathcal{A}'$-$\mathcal{A}''$-measurable

Under which additional conditions on $f$ do we've got $$\sigma(X)=\sigma(f\circ X)\;?$$ Please note, that $f\circ X$ is $\sigma(X)$-$\mathcal{A}''$-measurable in general. So, we only need to consider "$\subseteq$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some additional sufficient conditions are that $f$ maps measurable sets in $\mathcal{A}'$ to measurable sets in $\mathcal{A}''$ and $f$ is injective.

In one direction, let $X^{-1}(A)\in\sigma(X)$ for some $A\in\mathcal{A}'$. Let $f(A)=B$. By the added assumption above, $B\in\mathcal{A}''$ and, by injectivity, we also have $A=f^{-1}(B)$. This implies
$$
X^{-1}(A)=X^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(B)=(f\circ X)^{1}(B)\in\sigma(f\circ X)\implies \sigma(X)\subset\sigma(f\circ X).
$$
The reverse inclusion is easier:
$$
\forall B\in\mathcal{A}'':\quad(f\circ X)^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}[f^{-1}(B)]\in\sigma(X).
$$
Note that we need $f$ be measurable to ensure that $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{A}'$.

Comment: You say "by injectivity", but we've not assumed that $f$ is injective.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Ah, I was still thinking of your previous question. Let me change then.

Comment: Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable and $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. Then, $X$ is $\mathcal{A}^{\otimes\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}}$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$-measurable. Now, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$-measurable and injective, e.g. $$f(x):=\left(x_1,x_2-x_1,\ldots,x_n-x_{n-1}\right)$$ Can we use our statement in this scenario?

Comment: @0xbadf00d It seems YES because given the specific functional form of $f$, we see that $f^{-1}$ is continuous and therefore measurable, giving the sufficient conditions I stated in my answer.